# Partial Correlation with Nominal/Categorical Variable

Tags: categorical-data, partial-correlation

Is there a method to do a partial correlation with a nominal/categorical variable? If so: What is it called and how would you do it in R?

Comment: Given that you cannot even do "normal" correlation with nominal/categorical variables, the answer is "no".

Comment: Is there any other way to control for a nominal variable within a correlation?

Comment: You can estimate separate coefficients per group, which is... sort of like controlling, but not really.

Comment: The way I have learned to do what you want to do is to run a regression analysis with the continuous predictor (let's say x), the categorical variable (let's say c), and their interaction as predictors predicting the outcome variable. Then, if the interaction is significant, run the simple regression (with just x as predictor) separately for each level of c.